# Moving and resizing the Rectangle inside the Canvas In Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How I can move and resize a rectangle inside the Canvas horizontally in windows 8. I am trying to create a scale like control in my application. It will work like I can resize the rectangle horizontally and also it is possible to move the rectangle inside the canvas. Based on the rectangle position I will calculate the scale value. But when I try for the same I get stuck with resizing the rectangle(Drag on the left and right side of the rectangle to expand). Please anyone guide me to develop the same. No need to take effort for creating a sample for me. Just guide me, I will do the rest.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the positions and sizes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.setleft without more details, it's hard to understand where you're having troubles.

Comment: My main issue is re sizing the rectangle. I think there is nothing to do with Canvas.Left and Right.. :( –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are trying to allow for two different operations with the same gesture (single point of contact that moves on the surface). The behavior sounds to me like you want the rectangle to resize horizontally when you drag on the far left of right of it and to move around on the canvas when you drag anywhere else on it (please correct me if this is wrong).

I would think that you would want to use the Scale gesture for the resizing and a Translate gesture for the movement. In the past I have used [UIElement.ManipulationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode) with handlers for the appropriate manipulation events (e.g. ManipulationStarted, ManipulationCompleted, etc). I have also seen some mention of using [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) but haven't used it directly myself.

Once you have each action (drag or resize) managed by a distinct gesture you should just be able to update the size of the Rectangle by either directly changing its height and width values or by using a [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).